# Is there any way to see other player's pet hp bars?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm playing a Monk and my boyfriend is a Witch Doctor, and I was wondering if there is any way to see his pet's hp bars so I can heal them if needed.

I can see my own pet's hp (yes, I'm calling my Monk's Mystic Ally a "pet" :)) next to my portrait, and I can turn on other player health bars, but I don't see an option to turn on other player pet hp bars.

Is there a way to show other player's pet hp bars?

Comment: I thought minions were disabled in groups of larger than 1 unless they were part of the current story line.

Comment: @Sorean I think you are thinking of Hirelings, which are disabled. Minions that are summoned are not.

Comment: My apologies, my friends and I call any type of hired helped minions. My late night brain didn't pick that up.

Comment: @Sorean No problem, I rephrased my question to clarify I'm talking about pets and not followers (I guess I could have called them summoned minions too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched all over the Options and Interface menu, but there is nothing that seems to toggle this option. I guess Blizzard doesn't consider a fellow player's pet important enough to monitor for healing.